# Adding two sub-list if the first element is the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a beginner for python and i am trying to add two sub-list if the first element of the sub-list is the same. The number of sub-list is also not a constant.

I have tried looping through each element. But then again it compares with all elements in the list

enter code here

```
Input_list = [['A', 50, 10, 10, 10], ['B', 50, 40, 30, 70], ['C', 50, 20, 40, 30], ['A', 20, 20, 20, 20]]
Expected_list = [['A', 70, 30, 30, 30], ['B', 50, 40, 30, 70], ['C', 50, 20, 40, 30]]

for i in range(0, len(Input_list)):
for j in range(0, len(Input_list)):
    if Input_list[i][0] == Input_list[j][0]:
        print("True")
```

Comment: how is b and c having zero's?

Comment: Sorry thats my bad. Those values has to be the same

Comment: Have you tried to write any code for this? What part of it can't you figure out? "tried looping through every element" is very vague - could you show the code, so we can see what you did in that loop?

Comment: for i in range(0, len(Input_list)):
    for j in range(0, len(Input_list)):
        if Input_list[i][0] == Input_list[j][0]:
            print("True")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it:

```py
from operator import add

input_list = [['A', 50, 10, 10, 10], ['B', 50, 40, 30, 70], ['C', 50, 20, 40, 30], ['A', 20, 20, 20, 20]]

out = {}
for l in input_list:
    n = len(l)
    key = l[0]
    vals = [key] + list( map(add, l[1:n], out.get(key, [0]*n)[1:n]) )
    out[key] = vals
```

This uses a dictionary to keep track of the sublists:

```
In [24]: out
Out[24]:
{'A': ['A', 70, 30, 30, 30],
 'B': ['B', 50, 40, 30, 70],
 'C': ['C', 50, 20, 40, 30]}
```

`out.values()` yields what you're looking for:

```
In [25]: out.values()
Out[25]: dict_values([['A', 70, 30, 30, 30], ['B', 50, 40, 30, 70], ['C', 50, 20, 40, 30]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list to a dictionary and add the values if it has the same key.

```
nested_lists = [['A', 50, 10, 10, 10], ['B', 50, 40, 30, 70], ['C', 50, 20, 40, 30], ['A', 20, 20, 20, 20]]
dict = {}
for _list in nested_lists:
    key = _list[0]
    val = _list[1: ]
    if key in dict:
       dict[key] = [a + b for a, b in zip(dict[key], val)]
    dict.setdefault(key, val)
```